# Installing 32-bit libbz2.so.1 in 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm trying to install LabView on my computer (Ubuntu 15.04, 64-bit), but I need the 32-bit libbz2.so.1 library, based on [these instructions on the NI website](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/9FF1D10A973630AC862579F0002EC455) and googling elsewhere. However, the link to download getlibs to install it doesn't work, I can't find getlibs anywhere else (all the links are old and broken), and the other option I was considering (ia32-libs) isn't part of Ubuntu anymore. ([These instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23182765/how-to-install-ia32-libs-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts-trusty-tahr) were unsuccessful - I still got the error `Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate`).

How can I get this 32-bit version of the library to install LabView?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package for `libbz2.so.1` is `libbz2-1.0`. You can check this with the command:

```
apt-file search libbz2.so.1
```

Sample output:

```
% apt-file search libbz2.so.1 
libbz2-1.0: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1
libbz2-1.0: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0
libbz2-1.0: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
```

Therefore install the package for 32-bit with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0:i386
```

The library `ia32-libs` is no longer in the repositories. Check [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=ia32-libs).

Answer (score 1):

Are you still trying to do this? I (after much frustration) installed LabVIEW 8.5 32-bit on my new 64-bit Linux Mint Debian Edition 2 (LMDE2) machine today. Should be similar for Ubuntu.

You probably already did, but for those who don't know the first thing to do is set up multiarch (the ability to run 32-bit programs on 64-bit machines):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

This broke my Cinnamon; but running the update manager fixed it again. That's a LMDE specific problem; I don't think you need to worry about that. Then install some dependencies. `bzip2` includes the `libbz2.so.1` you were looking for, and (as already mentioned) `lib32z1` replaces `ia32-libs`:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
sudo apt-get install bzip2:i386
```

The LabVIEW installer looks in an unusual place for a file, so we make a link to it so it can find it:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
```

Now the LabVIEW installer will run, but LabVIEW won't start after the installer finishes because it needs `libGL.so.1`. This is where my method is a bit iffy and there is certainly a better method ... but this is how I did it:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-fglrx-glx:i386
```

This installed the `libGL.so.1`. It also killed my MDM (graphical login). So I dropped to a tty, made a copy of `libGL.so.1`, and then

```
sudo apt-get remove libgl1-fglrx-glx:i386
sudo cp libGL.so.1 /usr/lib
```

After that, everything worked :). I hope this helps you or someone.